# mysql query to graduate a record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the year and month and I would like to update the age of the client from the database as soon as 584 days have elapsed.

Example: year-1990 and month-12

This is my sample query:

```
....
where
(((TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) - TO_DAYS(`personel`.`birthdate`)) >= 584)
            AND (`personel`.`sex` = 4)))
```

Instead of birthdate in my query I have record on year and month.

Comment: Whats the problem? and why do you have 558 days in the query and 584 in the question?

Comment: As general advice - it's better to store client year of birth than age - you won't have this type of problems (with updating data).